# How to programmatically determine which (load balanced) tomcat server the webapp is running on

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a webapp that is running on two load balanced tomcat servers. What's the best way for the app to determine which server it's running on?

While I can tell from a sessionid which server it's running on (as .jvm1 and .jvm2 get appended), how can I get similar information in a background task (scheduled via Spring's @Scheduled annotation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be overkill and if there's another way it's probably better, but you might be able to query the tomcat Engine MBean and get it's `jvmRoute` property. The MBean is *usually* called `Catalina:type=Engine` or `Catalina:type=Engine,service=something` (see [here for more details](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/funcspecs/mbean-names.html)).

Comment: It might be overkill, but it does do exactly what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your instance on different machines, you can simply get hostName `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName()`